# program compilation error

Tags: c++, compilation

I wrote a program in C++. It includes a ctype header file.

While compiling it using the command `g++ sri.cpp` I get this error:

```
fatal error: ctype: No such file or directory
```

Kindly help me out with this.

Comment: I think you should include cctype: #include <cctype>

Answer (score 3):

Can you view us the code?
if you have wrote `#include <ctype>`, it should be `#include <cctype>` or `#include <ctype.h>`, but if this doesn't work then I suppose you don't have ctype at all to be compiled...